# Reading city name in Eastern Europe on passport from around 1900?

Tags: palaeography, poland, historical-gazetteer, place-names

Could you please help me to decipher the name of the city, region, and/or county? My grandma was born in the year 1901 and left Poland in the year 1925. She lived in Kovel, Poland for several years. I was told that her family was from Minsk and Ukraine. I have photocopies of her passport, which is in Polish and French. I don't understand the handwriting.

Please see the attached file for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about the town, but the locality is "pow. Kamień Koszyrski" - powiat Kamień Koszyrski.

Here's the list of "powiaty" (counties) in 2nd Polish Republic (1918-1939) : https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podzia%C5%82_administracyjny_II_Rzeczypospolitej#Wojew%C3%B3dztwo_poleskie

Current name of the county town is (English spelling) Kamin'-Kashyrs'kyi (Ukr. Камінь-Каширський), quite close to Kovel.

The village name looks like "Wider" to me. I can't find that one on the maps, but there's a https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4128840 Vyderta (Polish: Wyderta) close by. If the village was a small one (and especially if it had a mostly Polish population), it's not unlikely that it simply disappeared, with people moving away (and with all the other turmoil that happened in Wołyń/Volyn). Someone who can read Ukrainian should be able to help you find a list of existing villages in modern Kamin-Kashyrskyi Raion.

BTW, other parts of handwriting, in Polish:

```
 Zatrudnienie: bez zajęcia (employment: no profession)
 Wzrost: średni (height: average)
 Twarz: pociągła (face: long)
 Włosy: blond (hair colour: blonde)
 Oczy: szare (eyes: grey)
```

Comment: Couldn't [this](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/6078019#map=14/51.6051/24.5803) and [this](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/337504336) villages be good candidates ?